# How to initialize the ng-options with the first value in Json data?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to initialize n-options with the json data, But it is not initialize. I also tried ng-init. I want to initialize like in following image where **Metric** is initialize with **instance** and **Group By** by **Project** and **Value** by **Avg** and **Period** By **Last weeks**

[image]

DEMO : http://plnkr.co/edit/Ygkqlf60SLaLTtBaUoJf?p=preview
**Javascript**

```
 $http.get("data.json")
     .success(function(response){
         $scope.metrics=response.nova_meters.concat(response.glance_meters).concat(response.cinder_meters).concat(response.ipmi_meters).concat(response.neutron_meters).concat(response.swift_meters).concat(response.kwapi_meters);    
         $scope.groups=[{"name": "Project", "label": "Project"}];
     });
```

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="metric"  ng-options="value.name as value.label group by value.group for value in metrics" ng-init="metric='val1'">
</select>
```

**@shaishabroy  Thanks for suggesting, here is working demo**  http://plnkr.co/edit/Ygkqlf60SLaLTtBaUoJf?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem by this way. **Initialize the ng-model value from controller.**

In HTML:

```
<form>
            <div >
                <label >Metric: </label>
                <div>
                     <select ng-model="metric"  ng-options="value.label group by value.group for value in metrics" >
                    </select>    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Group by:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <select ng-model="group_by" ng-options="value.label for value in groups">


                    </select>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="stats_attr" >Value:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <select ng-model="stats_attr" ng-options="value.label for value in stats_attrs">

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Period:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <select ng-model="date_option" ng-options="value.label for value in date_options">

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

        </form>
```

In controller:

```
var app=angular.module('hz',[]);
 app.controller('ceilometerCtrl', function($scope, $http){
     //$scope.name="Neelabh";
     $http.get("data.json")
     .success(function(response){
         $scope.metrics=response.nova_meters.concat(response.glance_meters);
         $scope.metric =  $scope.metrics[0];
         $scope.groups=[{"name": "Project", "label": "Project"}];
         $scope.group_by = $scope.groups[0];
         //$scope.group_by=$scope.groups[0];
     });
     $scope.stats_attrs=[
      {
            "name": "Avg",          
            "label": "Avg"            
      },
      {
            "name": "Min",          
            "label": "Min"            
      },
      {
            "name": "Max",          
            "label": "Max"            
      },
      {
            "name": "Sum",          
            "label": "Sum"            
      },
   ];

   $scope.stats_attr = $scope.stats_attrs[0];
   $scope.date_options=[
      {
           "value" : 1,
           "label" : "Last day"
      },
      {
           "value" : 7,
           "label" : "Last week"
      },
      {
           "value" : 23,
           "label" : "Month to date"
      },
      {
           "value" : 30,
           "label" : "Last 30 days"
      },
      {
           "value" : 356,
           "label" : "Last year"
      },
      {
           "value" : "Other",
           "label" : "Other"
      }
   ];

   $scope.date_option = $scope.date_options[1];
 });
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, here is working demo  http://plnkr.co/edit/Ygkqlf60SLaLTtBaUoJf?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

use

```
ng-init <== with {{ }}
```

just small change in current code

```
<select ng-model="metric"  ng-options="value.name as value.label group by value.group for value in metrics" ng-init="{{ metric = metrics[0].name }}">
```

for concat try this

```
      $scope.metrics = [];
      for(var x in response){
        $scope.metrics = $scope.metrics.concat(response[x]);
      }
      console.log($scope.metrics)
```

the reason why it not allow other selection inspect your generated html code by angular !! all the values are selected and that's why it show us the last selected values . when we init our first selection it create problem to identify list that is grouped by so it select that all because  the reference of that group by list is your matrices var

Comment: Thanks Amit It works but It initialize from  the last element `image.size` But my first element is instance, One more thing How I concat `response.nova_meters.concat(response.glance_meters)` the response

Comment: because it's not able to find that selection  have you check in console it give you error

Comment: The problem with `image.size` is not cause by the init. Go on your plunker and try to select something different than `image.size` and it will always return this.

Comment: @NeelabhSingh The `value.name` was unkown. I gave more details in answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have edit the plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/V7myQjvYZ28ygVnGwcfp?p=preview

First of all, the problem with `image.size` is fix. You were using `ng-options="value.name as value.label group by value.group for value in metrics"` but `value.name` was unkown. It had to be `value.label`.

For the `init`, I use different `ng-init`:

```
ng-init="{{metric = metrics[0].label}}"
ng-init="date_option = date_options[1].label"
ng-init="{{group_by = groups[0].name}}"
ng-init="stats_attr = stats_attrs[0].name"
```

**Edit :**

It sounds like put `{{`had unexpected issue. So I remove them and init the value in the controller like this :

```
     $scope.group_by = $scope.groups[0].label;
     $scope.metric= $scope.metrics[0].label;
```

I did it only for this two because the others were working fine. You can do it for all 4.

I updated plunker link too

Comment: It has still the same problem It is not changing any value, it always shows `instance`

Comment: @NeelabhSingh this one come from `ng-init` .. working on. It's come from `{{`

Comment: I mean that  in metric selection options are not changing, please see your demo, it always show `instance`, if you try to change it will not http://plnkr.co/edit/V7myQjvYZ28ygVnGwcfp?p=preview

Comment: thx for answer, and tell me this approach, but metric option is not changing......

Answer (score 0):

You have to give an initial value to the model .

```
$scope.group_by =$scope.groups[0].name;
```

or simply

```
$scope.group_by = "Project";
```

Your metrics array is ----

```
[{"label":"instance","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"instance","title":"Existence of instance"},{"label":"cpu","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"ns","title":"CPU time used"},{"label":"cpu_util","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"%","title":"Average CPU utilisation"},{"label":"disk.read.requests","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"request","title":"Number of read requests"},{"label":"disk.write.requests","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"request","title":"Number of write requests"},{"label":"disk.read.bytes","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"B","title":"Volume of reads"},{"label":"disk.write.bytes","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"B","title":"Volume of writes"},{"label":"disk.read.requests.rate","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"request/s","title":"Average rate of read requests"},{"label":"disk.write.requests.rate","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"request/s","title":"Average rate of write requests"},{"label":"disk.read.bytes.rate","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"B/s","title":"Average rate of reads"},{"label":"disk.write.bytes.rate","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"B/s","title":"Average volume of writes"},{"label":"network.incoming.bytes","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"B","title":"Number of incoming bytes on the network for a VM interface"},{"label":"network.outgoing.bytes","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"B","title":"Number of outgoing bytes on the network for a VM interface"},{"label":"network.incoming.packets","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"packet","title":"Number of incoming packets for a VM interface"},{"label":"network.outgoing.packets","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"packet","title":"Number of outgoing packets for a VM interface"},{"label":"network.incoming.bytes.rate","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"B/s","title":"Average rate per sec of incoming bytes on a VM network interface"},{"label":"network.outgoing.bytes.rate","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"B/s","title":"Average rate per sec of outgoing bytes on a VM network interface"},{"label":"network.incoming.packets.rate","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"packet/s","title":"Average rate per sec of incoming packets on a VM network interface"},{"label":"network.outgoing.packets.rate","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"packet/s","title":"Average rate per sec of outgoing packets on a VM network interface"},{"label":"instance:m1.nano","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"instance","title":"Duration of instance type m1.nano (openstack flavour)"},{"label":"image","group":"Image (Glance)","unit":"image","title":"Image existence check"},{"label":"image.size","group":"Image (Glance)","unit":"B","title":"Uploaded image size"}];
```

There is no name field here which you are using.

Change to this

```
<select ng-model="metric"  ng-options="value.title as value.label group by value.group for value in metrics" ng-init="metric='val1'">
                </select>
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.metric=$scope.metrics[0].title;
```

Comment: its not working, and one more thing   `$scope.group_by=$scope.groups[0];` not `$scope.metric =$scope.groups[0].name;`

Comment: Yes according to your code in the question its $scope.metric =$scope.groups[0].name; but as per your plunker its $scope.group_by=$scope.groups[0];

Comment: It not working But see the again Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Ygkqlf60SLaLTtBaUoJf?p=preview  it is woking but initialize with the last element `image.size` but it should be `instance` because its first element

Comment: @Neelabh there is no name filed in your array so you should either change it to unit or label. Your array is [{"label":"instance","group":"Compute (Nova)","unit":"instance","title":"Existence of instance"}.....

Answer (score 0):

As per your plunker the following code will initialize the select with the first element of the array:

```
<select ng-model="metric"  
        ng-options="value.name as value.label group by value.group for value in metrics" 
        ng-init="$first"></select>
```

Notice the addition of **init="$first"**.